# In Android, is the value of View id in two different layouts always the same?

Tags: android, enums

I have a radio group with the same radio buttons in two different layouts.
The radio buttons have the same ids in both layouts.

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroupAccess"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioGroupAccessOptionPublic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="public"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioGroupAccessOptionPrivate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="private"/>

</RadioGroup>
```

Now, I have an Enum (AccessType) for Public/Private values.
I want to be able to find out which Enum value corresponds to a given RadioButton id value.

Can I rely on the id value to always be the same, even though I have it defined in two different layouts?
And if not, which view id value does R.id.radioGroupAccessOptionPublic return?
Is other words, can I rely on the following code to be consistent?

```
public static AccessType getAccessTypeByIdentifier(int radioButtonID) {
    AccessType type;

    switch (radioButtonID) {
        case R.id.radioGroupAccessOptionPublic:
            type = AccessType.PUBLIC;
            break;
        case R.id.radioGroupAccessOptionPrivate:
        default:
            type = AccessType.PRIVATE;
            break;
    }

    return type;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your ids will be the same, you could check the R.java file also for verification

and actually, you could set values on `res/values/ids.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="radioGroupAccessOptionPublic" type="id"/>
    <item name="radioGroupAccessOptionPrivate" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

and then use it like that

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroupAccess"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@id/radioGroupAccessOptionPublic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="public"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@id/radioGroupAccessOptionPrivate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="private"/>

</RadioGroup>
```

> without the '+' before the 'id' part.

Comment: Excellent! Great suggestion with adding the id to resources. Now I'm more relaxed :)

Comment: yeah, now you can use the autocomplete to complete the id of a view with a consistency between values.